# Conditional if on a dataframe based on another one

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
ID      VAR
a       3
b       2
c       6
b       8
z       1
c       5
b       7
```

and another one that counts the number of times that one ID appears

```
numb    nrec

a       1
b       3
c       2
z       1
```

What I would like to do is to change the ID name of all the IDs that has just one record, p.e.

```
ID      VAR
-1      3
b       2
c       6
b       8
-1      1
c       5
b       7
```

Comment: What do you want to change it to? Can you show an example of what your changed data frame would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an ugly solution

```
> ind <- as.character(df2$numb[df2$nrec==1])
> df1$ID <- as.character(df1$ID)
> df1$ID[as.character(df1$ID) %in% ind] <- "-1"
> df1
  ID VAR
1 -1   3
2  b   2
3  c   6
4  b   8
5 -1   1
6  c   5
7  b   7
```

If you want `ID` to be factor again, then `df1$ID <- as.factor(df1$ID)`

A better way is using `revalue` from plyr package:

```
library(plyr)
df1$ID <- with(df1, revalue(ID, c("a"="-1", "z"=-1)))
```

EDIT: a cleaner way using base functions

```
ind <- as.character(df2$numb[df2$nrec==1])
levels(df1$ID)[levels(df1$ID)==ind] <- "-1"
```

You can even do it directly using only `df1`, no need to use `df2`. Using `table` and some indexing...

```
levels(df1$ID)[levels(df1$ID)==with(df1, levels(ID)[table(ID)==1])] <- "-1"
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain me how the %in% operator works? Does it work as two nested for loops?

Comment: @user2287387 take a look at `?"%in%"`, you'll all the relevan explanation in there.